# store total total price in document or resolve by aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I got a **supplies** collection which contains document of following design:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("532807bdf09ae6e7464191c1"),
    supplier: {
        $ref: "suppliers",
        $id: ObjectId("5328078cf09ae6e7464191c0")
    },
    state: {
        created: ISODate("2013-12-10T00:00:00Z"),
        shipped: ISODate("2013-12-11T00:00:00Z"),
        cleared: ISODate("2013-12-11T00:00:00Z")
    },
    materials: [
        {
            material: {
                $ref: "materials",
                $id: ObjectId("53280782f09ae6e7464191b9")
            },
            quantity: 1,
            price: 4.8
        },
        {
            material: {
                $ref: "materials",
                $id: ObjectId("53280782f09ae6e7464191ba")
            },
            quantity: 1,
            price: 3.5
        },
        {
            material: {
                $ref: "materials",
                $id: ObjectId("53280782f09ae6e7464191bb")
            },
            quantity: 1,
            price: 4.1
        },
        {
            material: {
                $ref: "materials",
                $id: ObjectId("53280782f09ae6e7464191bc")
            },
            quantity: 1,
            price: 4.3
        },
        {
            material: {
                $ref: "materials",
                $id: ObjectId("53280782f09ae6e7464191bd")
            },
            quantity: 1,
            price: 3.6
        },
        {
            material: {
                $ref: "materials",
                $id: ObjectId("53280782f09ae6e7464191be")
            },
            quantity: 1,
            price: 3.15
        },
        {
            material: {
                $ref: "materials",
                $id: ObjectId("53280782f09ae6e7464191bf")
            },
            quantity: 1,
            price: 5
        }
    ]
}
```

In the business logic I would now sometimes want to know the total price of a single **supplies** document.

This could be achieved by *aggregation*:

```
db.supplies.aggregate({
  $unwind: "$materials" // go through material array
},
{
  $project: {
    "total": {
      // calculate price of each item (1.19 is vat)
      $multiply: ["$materials.quantity", "$materials.price", 1.19]
    }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "total": {
      // sum all items together
      $sum: "$total"
    }
  }
});
```

However is it clever to do so or should I just add a "total" field to the document?

Comment: Though I am a fan of clever things, and aggregation is a very nice and clever thing. Possibly ask yourself, for a single document then what is the cost of storing a total? And, is it likely that you will have the data all together in order to calculate that? Aggregation is a clever thing, but is it better in this case? **You**, are probably the best one to answer that.

Comment: @NeilLunn both have there benefits and downsides. Main benefit of using aggregation is that we could update prices without needing to care about a total property however this does not happen quite often so I guess your right with using an extra field!

Comment: That is all fine. And possibly your question could benefit from the additional information of how you maintain your data. As it stands, the current question seems very open to opinions. If you believe there is something you need to solve. Then inform us of it, and you are then likely to get something other than a recommendation. Just trying to fairly inform that this does not presently meet the "on-topic" [guidelines for the site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you can change it to do so then do. There [more suited forums](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) for discussions.